# Maybe add a tag for the `kit-clj` Clojure web microframework, alongside the `luminus` tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation-request

It seems the *luminus* tag is there on Stack Overflow, but according to the [Luminus website](https://luminusweb.com/), there appears to be a (relatively new) successor to the Luminus Clojure microframework called [Kit](https://kit-clj.github.io/) (not to be confused with the *http-kit* tag or the *http-kit* framework itself). I looked all over the Stack Overflow *Tags* section, and there does not seem to be a *kit-clj* tag or anything related to the Kit web microframework.

This tag may be suitable for (newer) questions related to Clojure web development that do not have a specific *luminus* tag, for example using the *ring* or *compojure* tag. Here are some examples:

[Static files in Compojure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77510509/adding-static-files-to-compojure)

[Asset files not being loaded in Compojure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982550/asset-files-are-not-being-loaded-even-though-server-is-serving-them)

Is there any chance someone could add this tag?

Here are some links to the specific parts of the pages I was looking at, in case anyone needs these:

[Luminus web - Kit backlink](https://luminusweb.com/#:%7E:text=Check%20out%20Kit%2C%20a%20successor%20to%20Luminus)

[(Potential) tag *kit-clj* - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kit-clj)

[Tag *luminus* - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luminus)

Comment: Are there any questions that need this tag? (Please [edit].) If not, then there's no need for the tag nor any good way to create it (since you have to add a new tag to a question to create it).

Comment: I have made some modifications, does it seem relevant for (newer) questions with Clojure routing library tags like `ring` and/or `compojure` that do not explicitly have the `luminus` tag?

Comment: @redbraces are the questions you've linked actually about Kit? If not we probably won't be adding that tag to the question. Note that tags are used to categorize what a question is about, they are not used to categorize what the answers can potentially use. If you find a question that is actually about Kit and doesn't have any tags for that you can [edit] and add those here. The community might potentially add that tag for you if it makes sense to them. On the other hand if **you** have any (on-topic) questions about Kit feel free to ask them and add them here to your question.

Comment: A second consideration is: clj-kit or kit-clj? Using clj as a prefix in tags seems to be more common than using it as a suffix.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I do think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77510509/adding-static-files-to-compojure) is probably about Kit, due to the fact that it was posted 2 days ago, and according to the question, the user has their project running on localhost:3000. This is also the default port Kit runs on, and plus Compojure is used with Kit a lot of the time as a routing library.

Comment: @ErikA, `clj-kit` seems like a viable option, it is just that it may be misleading to a Clojure toolkit or something like that, although the tag is not already taken. It could work though!